# redis RedisConnectionFailureException SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: exception, redis

```
RedisConnectionFailureException    cleanupExpiredSessions  
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

Comment: describe your question

Comment: redis often down by itself,the log contains at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisSessionExpirationPolicy.cleanExpiredSessions(RedisSessionExpirationPolicy.java:111)
 at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.cleanupExpiredSessions(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:216)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor206.invoke(Unknown Source)

Comment: Welcome to SO @kyzh101 please see this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask